# MS Access error 6124 when using UNC path to a .doc template

Tags: ms-access-2010, unc

I am using the Word Document template to create a letter from Access database.

From the form in Access I can select records which are used to generate a letter based on predefined template.

The template is located in the server. The users have access to that location but it is not mapped in their systems.
So my problem starts when I set the UNC path to the template in the code:

```
Set doc = oWord.Documents.Open("\\srv01\Tool\Templates\Letter.doc")
```

I get an *error 6124: You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected.*

When I set the path to the mapped drive it works fine:

```
Set doc = oWord.Documents.Open("T:\Tool\Templates\Letter.doc")
```

But the thing is it works only for me because I have it mapped, but as I mentioned above my users don't have it mapped.

So is there any workaround?

P.S. I thought about creation of a template folder in the user's local drive but I want to store it in the safe location and don't want to face with sudden deletion or other corruption of this folder by the user.

Comment: How about copying the template locally at the start of the procedure?

Comment: Copying from the server to the local drive? Yes, it might work... I'll try. Thanks for an idea.